# What is the function of parse_args() and where do i need to pass the argument

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

This is my code,

I am trying to learn argparse could anyone explain me the code

```
# enter code here
import argparse
parser= argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("radius",type=int,help="radius")
parser.add_argument("height",type=int,help="height")
args=parser.parse_args()
def add(radius,height):
   return radius+height
so=add(args.radius,args.height)
print("the sum is",so)
**
#this was the output
#usage: arg_parsedemo.py [-h] radius height
#arg_parsedemo.py: error: the following arguments are required:
#radius,height
```

Comment: How did you invoke this script?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

parse_args will take the arguments you provide on the command line when you run your program and interpret them according to the arguments you have added to your ArgumentParser object.

You've added two argument types to your parser, radius and height, they are positional because you have not included a "--" on their name, which means you need to provide them when you run the program. In order to run your program, you will need to run it like this:
    python arg_parsedemo.py 50 100

50 will be set to the radius and 100 will be set to the height.